# How Can I pull data from multiple tabs into one google sheet via Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All,

Before I explain the problem, I would like to present some information about what it is that I am working with.

Tab 1 can have columns: Date, State,Actual/Forecast,Value

Tab 2 can have columns: Date, Actual/Forecast, Value

Tab 3 will have: Date, Actual/Forecast, Value

I need to pull date, actual/forecast, and value columns from tabs 1 and 2 and populate into tab 3 in a proper table format without any blank rows/breaks for column A. I would ideally like to do this by the click of a button on tab 3. How would I go about doing this? I found that I could copy over one sheet's data via:

```
function MoveData() {
var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var ss3 = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet3");
ss.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(ss3.getRange("A2"), {contentsOnly:true});
ss.getRange("C2:C").copyTo(ss3.getRange("B2"), {contentsOnly:true});
ss.getrange("D2:D").copyTo(ss3.getrange("C2"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

The next step would be to populate data from the second sheet right below what is being pulled via this function.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you described.

```
function MoveData() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2");
var ss3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet3");
ss.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(ss3.getRange("A2"), {contentsOnly:true});
ss.getRange("C2:C").copyTo(ss3.getRange("B2"), {contentsOnly:true});
ss.getrange("D2:D").copyTo(ss3.getRange("C2"), {contentsOnly:true});
var nextRow=ss3.getLastRow()+1;//I assume that the above results in 
same size columns.
ss2.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(ss3.getRange(nextRow,1), 
{contentsOnly:true});
ss2.getRange("B2:B").copyTo(ss3.getRange(nextRow,2), 
{contentsOnly:true});
ss2.getrange("C2:C").copyTo(ss3.getRange(nextRow,3), 
{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me so quickly. I actually received the following error:
TypeError: Cannot find function getrange in object Sheet.

it was able to pull in data from tab 1 then presented me with that error

Comment: I made a last minute change because getLastRow() is going to give a different result the second time it's called than it did the first time.  So I moved it into an intermediate variable.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response! Still getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: @sorosh there is a small typo in the code, getrange should be getRange ! 2 times in the code

Comment: oh okay let me try!

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I just copied your code and modified it a little.

Comment: The error I am getting is the following: TypeError: Cannot find function getrange in object Sheet.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised the syntax checker doesn't catch things like that.

Comment: You should use autocomplete to avoid such errors :) control + space

Comment: Unfortunately - i am still running into the same error so it doesn't seem to be the syntax? unless i'm doing something wrong. I had to change the second set of getranges but other than that nothing has changed.

Comment: To be sure do a search and replace on getrange replaced by getRange and check after that

Comment: That did it... apologies! Thank you guys VERY much!